# Why is $E(ee')$ a matrix?

Tags: regression, covariance-matrix, linear-algebra

One of the assumptions of linear regression is that $E(ee') = \sigma^2 * I $, where I is the identity matrix and sigma squared is the variance of residuals. Why is $E(ee')$ a matrix, though? $ee'$ is the dot product of the residuals so it is a 1x1 vector. How do we get a matrix out of a 1x1 vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You obtain this by using matrix algebra. $\epsilon=(\epsilon_1,\dots,\epsilon_T)^\top$ is a $T \times 1$ column vector. Now look at: \begin{align}
\epsilon\cdot \epsilon^\top=\begin{pmatrix} \epsilon_1 \\ \vdots \\\epsilon_T\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix} \epsilon_1 & \dots & \epsilon_T\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} \epsilon_1^2 & \dots & \epsilon_1\epsilon_T \\ \vdots & \dots & \vdots \\ \epsilon_T\epsilon_1 & \dots & \epsilon_T^2 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

This is a $T \times T$ matrix.

Regards